# Doing fgets without the newline

Tags: c

`fgets` adds in a trailing newline. Is there a suggested pattern to use which strips the newline?

```
int main(void)
{
    char book[50];
    puts("Enter the name of the book: ");
    fgets(book, 50, stdin);
    printf("The name of the book is: %s", book);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: @SuperStormer — Yes, it does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input